# Permission denied for curl command

Tags: macos, unix, curl, permissions

I'm working through this book for grad school (see URL below) and I've gotten to the part on curl programs.

I'm supposed to enter this command and have a txt file of 30 days of miami weather.

```
curl "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/MIA/1992/08/[01-30]/DailyHistory.html?&format=1" >> miamiweather.txt
```

Instead I get

```
-bash: miamiweather.tx: Permission denied
```

I am very new to mac, so I think it may be an issue with the permission. This book was made before the maverick update, so could there be something in the update that interferes with the curl command? I've checked apple help pages and forums to no avail.

Edit: forgot the book url 
[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Computing-Biologists-Steven-Haddock/dp/0878933913](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0878933913)

Edit: I did not cd into a directory. I was creating the file in my home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are either in a write protected directory or the file is write protected.

Try:

```
ls -l miamiweather.txt
```

to see if the file is write protected.

Try

```
cd
```

to get to your home directory and then try the curl command again.

Comment: I get all the weather info for the specified 30 days from the 30 URLs, but I get the following errors                                           curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ls
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: miamiweather.txt

Comment: I did not cd into a directory, that was the problem